# Addition for multiple textboxes dynamically when entering a value to a TextBox in C# .NET

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, addition

I am designing a form for a salary table in C# using .NET forms (in Visual Studio).

When entering the various values to the textboxes, the final textbox should be displayed with addition of all the other textboxes. If I remove a value from any textbox, the result of all remaining textboxes should be displayed.

**Code**

```
float grossalery;
float afterleaves;
float n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7;private void txtCCA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtCCA.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        n1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtGTC.Text);
        n2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtPF.Text);
        n3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtbasicsalery.Text);
        n4 = Convert.ToInt32(txthoserent.Text);
        n5 = Convert.ToInt32(txtlicrent.Text);
        n6 = Convert.ToInt32(txtDA.Text);
        n7 = Convert.ToInt32(txtCCA.Text);
        grossalery = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7;
        txtgrosssalery.Text = Convert.ToString(grossalery);
    } else {
        txtCCA.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: is it specifically these 7 textboxes or are those all the textboxes on the form? And what is the exact problem your currently having? it looks like your error handling needs to be per textbox with this event shared

Comment: I dont want to use this code,,its just an alternate soln to my problem

and No,It is not specifically these 7 textboxes..

Comment: Write this code in a function and call that in text changed event of all the textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set all textboxes TextChanged event to txtCCA_TextChanged**

```
private void txtCCA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sumNumbers()
}
private void sumNumbers()
{
    float.TryParse(txtGTC.Text, out n1);
    float.TryParse(txtPF.Text, out n2);
    float.TryParse(txtbasicsalery.Text, out n3);
    float.TryParse(txthoserent.Text, out n4);
    float.TryParse(txtlicrent.Text, out n5);
    float.TryParse(txtDA.Text, out n6);
    float.TryParse(txtCCA.Text, out n7);
    grossalery = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7;
    txtgrosssalery.Text = Convert.ToString(grossalery);
}
```

Comment: Call that in all text changed event, if you want the value to change for any textbox value change

Comment: That's what i said at the first line for `txtCCA_TextChanged`

Comment: Why,,I'm getting this error while parsing the textbox values

The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid argumen

Comment: Ok. I changed `int.tryParse` to `float.TryParse`. it should work now

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sumNumbers()
  {
      float.TryParse(txtGTC.Text, out n1);
      float.TryParse(txtPF.Text, out n2);
      float.TryParse(txtbasicsalery.Text, out n3);
      float.TryParse(txthoserent.Text, out n4);
      float.TryParse(txtlicrent.Text, out n5);
      float.TryParse(txtDA.Text, out n6);
      float.TryParse(txtCCA.Text, out n7);
      grossalery = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7;
      txtgrosssalery.Text = Convert.ToString(grossalery);
  }
```

private void txtGTC_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          sumNumbers();
      }

```
  private void txtPF_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      sumNumbers();
  }

  private void txtbasicsalery_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      sumNumbers();
  }

  private void txthoserent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      sumNumbers();
  }

  private void txtlicrent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      sumNumbers();
  }

  private void txtDA_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      sumNumbers();
  }
```